# I am getting a type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String >' in type cast

Tags: flutter, typeerror, riverpod, appwrite

I am creating a flutter app and this is the part of code where i am getting the error. I am using flutter_riverpod package as my provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/common/common.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/features/tweet/controller/tweet_controller.dart';

class TweetList extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TweetList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ref.watch(getTweetsProvider).when(
        data: (tweets) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tweets.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final tweet = tweets[index];
              return Text(tweet.text);
            },
          );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
              errorText: error.toString(),
            ),
        loading: () => const Loader());
  }
}
```

The ErrorText widget simply displays the error on screen

This is the controller class

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/apis/storage_api.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/apis/tweet_api.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/core/core.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/features/auth/controller/auth_controller.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/models/tweet_model.dart';

final getTweetsProvider = FutureProvider((ref) {
  final tweetController = ref.watch(tweetControllerProvider.notifier);
  return tweetController.getTweets();
});

final tweetControllerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TweetController, bool>(
  (ref) {
    return TweetController(
      ref: ref,
      tweetAPI: ref.watch(tweetAPIProvider),
      storageAPI: ref.watch(storageAPIProvider),
    );
  },
);

class TweetController extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  final TweetAPI _tweetAPI;
  final StorageAPI _storageAPI;
  final Ref _ref;
  TweetController({
    required Ref ref,
    required TweetAPI tweetAPI,
    required StorageAPI storageAPI,
  })  : _ref = ref,
        _tweetAPI = tweetAPI,
        _storageAPI = storageAPI,
        super(false);

  Future<List<TweetModel>> getTweets() async {
    final tweetList = await _tweetAPI.getTweets();
    return tweetList
        .map<TweetModel>((tweet) => TweetModel.fromMap(tweet.data))
        .toList();
  }

  void shareTweet({
    required List<File> images,
    required String text,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) {
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      showSnackBar(context, 'Please enter text');
    }
    if (images.isNotEmpty) {
      _shareImageTweet(
        images: images,
        text: text,
        context: context,
      );
    } else {
      _shareTextTweet(
        text: text,
        context: context,
      );
    }
  }

  void _shareImageTweet({
    required List<File> images,
    required String text,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    final hashTags = _getHashTagsFromText(text);
    String link = _getLinkFromText(text);
    final user = _ref.read(currentUserDetailsProvider).value!;
    final imageLinks = await _storageAPI.uploadImages(images);
    TweetModel tweetModel = TweetModel(
      text: text,
      hashTags: hashTags,
      link: link,
      imageLinks: imageLinks,
      userId: user.uid,
      tweetType: TweetType.image,
      tweetedAt: DateTime.now(),
      likes: const [],
      commentIds: const [],
      id: '',
      reSharedCount: 0,
    );
    final res = await _tweetAPI.shareTweet(tweetModel);
    state = false;
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) => null);
  }

  void _shareTextTweet({
    required String text,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    final hashTags = _getHashTagsFromText(text);
    String link = _getLinkFromText(text);
    final user = _ref.read(currentUserDetailsProvider).value!;
    TweetModel tweetModel = TweetModel(
      text: text,
      hashTags: hashTags,
      link: link,
      imageLinks: const [],
      userId: user.uid,
      tweetType: TweetType.text,
      tweetedAt: DateTime.now(),
      likes: const [],
      commentIds: const [],
      id: '',
      reSharedCount: 0,
    );
    final res = await _tweetAPI.shareTweet(tweetModel);
    state = false;
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) => null);
  }

  String _getLinkFromText(String text) {
    String link = '';
    List<String> wordsInSentence = text.split(' ');
    for (String word in wordsInSentence) {
      if (word.startsWith('https://') ||
          word.startsWith('http://') ||
          word.startsWith('www.')) {
        link = word;
      }
    }
    return link;
  }

  List<String> _getHashTagsFromText(String text) {
    List<String> hashTags = [];
    List<String> wordsInSentence = text.split(' ');
    for (String word in wordsInSentence) {
      if (word.startsWith('#')) {
        hashTags.add(word);
      }
    }
    return hashTags;
  }
}
```

This is the api class

```
import 'package:appwrite/appwrite.dart';
import 'package:appwrite/models.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:fpdart/fpdart.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/constants/appwrite_constants.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/core/core.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/models/tweet_model.dart';

final tweetAPIProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return TweetAPI(db: ref.watch(appwriteDataBaseProvider));
});

abstract class ITweetAPI {
  FutureEither<Document> shareTweet(TweetModel tweetModel);
  Future<List<Document>> getTweets();
}

class TweetAPI implements ITweetAPI {
  final Databases _db;
  TweetAPI({required Databases db}) : _db = db;

  @override
  FutureEither<Document> shareTweet(TweetModel tweetModel) async {
    try {
      final document = await _db.createDocument(
        databaseId: AppwriteConstants.databaseId,
        collectionId: AppwriteConstants.tweetsCollectionId,
        documentId: ID.unique(),
        data: tweetModel.toMap(),
      );
      return right(document);
    } on AppwriteException catch (e, st) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.message ?? "Some unexpected error occurred", st),
      );
    } catch (e, st) {
      return left(
        Failure(e.toString(), st),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Document>> getTweets() async {
    final documents = await _db.listDocuments(
      databaseId: AppwriteConstants.databaseId,
      collectionId: AppwriteConstants.tweetsCollectionId,
    );
    return documents.documents;
  }
}
```

and this is the model class

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:twitter_clone/core/core.dart';

@immutable
class TweetModel {
  final String text;
  final List<String> hashTags;
  final String link;
  final List<String> imageLinks;
  final String userId;
  final TweetType tweetType;
  final DateTime tweetedAt;
  final List<String> likes;
  final List<String> commentIds;
  final String id;
  final int reSharedCount;

  const TweetModel({
    required this.text,
    required this.hashTags,
    required this.link,
    required this.imageLinks,
    required this.userId,
    required this.tweetType,
    required this.tweetedAt,
    required this.likes,
    required this.commentIds,
    required this.id,
    required this.reSharedCount,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'text': text,
      'hashTags': hashTags,
      'link': link,
      'imageLinks': imageLinks,
      'userId': userId,
      'tweetType': tweetType.type,
      'tweetedAt': tweetedAt.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'likes': likes,
      'commentIds': commentIds,
      'reSharedCount': reSharedCount,
    };
  }

  factory TweetModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TweetModel(
      text: map['text'] as String,
      hashTags: map['hashTags'] as List<String>,
      link: map['link'] as String,
      imageLinks: map['imageLinks'] as List<String>,
      userId: map['userId'] as String,
      tweetType: (map['tweetType'] as String).toTweetTypeEnum(),
      tweetedAt: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['tweetedAt']),
      likes: map['likes'] as List<String>,
      commentIds: map['commentIds'] as List<String>,
      id: map['\$id'] as String,
      reSharedCount: map['reSharedCount'] as int,
    );
  }

  TweetModel copyWith({
    String? text,
    List<String>? hashTags,
    String? link,
    List<String>? imageLinks,
    String? userId,
    TweetType? tweetType,
    DateTime? tweetedAt,
    List<String>? likes,
    List<String>? commentIds,
    String? id,
    int? reSharedCount,
  }) {
    return TweetModel(
      text: text ?? this.text,
      hashTags: hashTags ?? this.hashTags,
      link: link ?? this.link,
      imageLinks: imageLinks ?? this.imageLinks,
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      tweetType: tweetType ?? this.tweetType,
      tweetedAt: tweetedAt ?? this.tweetedAt,
      likes: likes ?? this.likes,
      commentIds: commentIds ?? this.commentIds,
      id: id ?? this.id,
      reSharedCount: reSharedCount ?? this.reSharedCount,
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried different sources to look for the solution. I searched this site to but did not find the solution.Please do help I am stuck here.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact line at which the error occurs?

Comment: I think it is happening in controller class as that is the only place that I am getting the data from for the TweetList class. It is the first two provider. I have provided all the code that the TweetList class has access to in the question.

Comment: Isn't there any error message shown? Could you please add the **whole** error message to your question?

Comment: I had a problem with my model. Thanks for your help though. I'll be closing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed the models fromMap function from this

```
 factory TweetModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
return TweetModel(
  text: map['text'] as String,
  hashTags: map['hashTags'] as List<String>,
  link: map['link'] as String,
  imageLinks: map['imageLinks'] as List<String>,
  userId: map['userId'] as String,
  tweetType: (map['tweetType'] as String).toTweetTypeEnum(),
  tweetedAt: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['tweetedAt']),
  likes: map['likes'] as List<String>,
  commentIds: map['commentIds'] as List<String>,
  id: map['\$id'] as String,
  reSharedCount: map['reSharedCount'] as int,
);
```

}

to this

```
factory TweetModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
return TweetModel(
  text: map['text'] ?? '',
  hashtags: List<String>.from(map['hashtags']),
  link: map['link'] ?? '',
  imageLinks: List<String>.from(map['imageLinks']),
  uid: map['uid'] ?? '',
  tweetType: (map['tweetType'] as String).toTweetTypeEnum(),
  tweetedAt: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['tweetedAt']),
  likes: List<String>.from(map['likes']),
  commentIds: List<String>.from(map['commentIds']),
  id: map['\$id'] ?? '',
  reshareCount: map['reshareCount']?.toInt() ?? 0,
  retweetedBy: map['retweetedBy'] ?? '',
  repliedTo: map['repliedTo'] ?? '',
);
```

}
and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to specify what type you want to return from your provider as a good practice.

```
final getTweetsProvider = FutureProvider<List<TweetModel>>((ref) {
  final tweetController = ref.watch(tweetControllerProvider.notifier);
  return tweetController.getTweets();
});
```

If you don't specify explicitly, Dart will infer the type of the future dynamically, it can be the cause why it consider as List instead of List (for your text I suppose)
Also if you specify, Dart can highlight when the type returned is not what expected

Comment: Still getting the same error.